# find unknown extension of a file to load async having only the file name

Tags: jquery, file, asynchronous, load

In my markup there's a nav with some links; on clicking on them I load an external page into the main content, in this way:

```
$('nav a').click(function() {

    rel = $(this).attr('rel');

    link = 'includes/'+rel+'.html'; /* <-- this is the matter */

    $('content').empty().append($('<div id="mainframe"></div>').load(link, function() {

        /* do the stuff */

    });
```

});

Well, everything was ok until I was told that maybe contents to load can be not only .html but .jsp and more. 
So, I was wondering if I can find the unknown file extension in order to write something like the following pseudocode.

```
link = 'includes/'+rel+'findRelativeFileExtension();
```

Unfortunately I can't use server-side language and I think that it's not elegant to write file extension in "rel" attribute.

Thank you in advance, any help will be sincerly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data-attributes in your a-tag. Ex `<a data-filename="nnn.jsp">download</a>` 
And read it with  `rel = $(this).attr('data-filename');`

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data

Comment: If you cant get the data elsewhere (serverside) then you will have to store it in the markup and the best way to do this is with custom data-attributes. Thats what they are for :)

Comment: Ok, I undesrtand. If there is not another way I take this solution. Thank you so much :) I accept your answer. You can vote for my question anymore if you want. :)